# how to use django.core.management.sql.sql_create?

Tags: sql, django

I want to use this function:
django.core.management.sql.sql_create in my view, to get the "CREATE" statements

the function gets 3 arguments:

app, style, connection

what is "app"?? is it a specific object or just the app name?!

I know style is something to do with colors... I reckon django.core.management.color.colorstyle() should work..

what about connection, how do I get this one?

thanks

=========================== edited from here down

ok, after some time, I figured the things, this is what I ended up with:

```
def sqldumper(model):
    """gets a db model, and returns the SQL statements to build it on another SQL-able db"""
    #This is how django inserts a new record
    #u'INSERT INTO "polls_poll" ("question", "pub_date") VALUES (GE!!, 2011-05-03 15:45:23.254000)'

    result = "BEGIN;\n"
    #add CREATE TABLE statements
    result+= '\n'.join(sql_create(models.get_app('polls'), color_style(), connections.all()[0]))+"\n"
    result+= '\n'.join(sql_custom(models.get_app('polls'), color_style(), connections.all()[0]))+"\n"
    result+= '\n'.join(sql_indexes(models.get_app('polls'), color_style(), connections.all()[0]))+"\n"
    result+= '\n'

    #add INSERT INTO staetements
    units = model.objects.all().values()
    for unit in units:
        statement = "INSERT INTO yourapp.model "+str(tuple(unit.keys()))+" VALUES " + str(tuple(unit.values()))+"\n"
        result+=statement

    result+="\nCOMMIT;\n"
    return result.encode('utf-8')
```

it's still a bit weird, because you get the CREATE TABLE for the whole app, but the INSERT INTO only for the model you ask.... but it's fixable from here

Answer (score 0):

It's the models.py module found in one of your apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myproject.myapp',
    )
```

When I printed it, I got `< module 'myproject.myapp.models' from '...' >`. I used the ellipses instead of typing the entire models.py file's path.

Comment: okay, I kinda figured it out - I edited my question (because as a newbie you're not allowed to post answers to your own question... :) thanks Bryce!